# Events processing missing in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming

We are receiving events from event hub and used spark streaming as processing . For testing purpose I have sent 300 events in sequence , I have two streams as I mentioned below but I see some data is missing in both the streams some times first stream is working correctly and second stream is missing to process, first stream is just to append and delete, second stream is aggregation df1.writeStream.queryName(f"display1").format(
"delta"
).foreachBatch(
lambda dataframe, _: fun1(spark, path,df1)
).trigger(
processingTime="30 seconds"
).outputMode(
"update"
).start()

updated_df = func(spark, df_with_signals)

query=updated_df.writeStream.queryName("display2").format(
"delta"
).foreachBatch(
lambda dataframe, _: fun2(spark, dataframe)
).trigger(
processingTime="2 seconds"
).outputMode(
"update"
)

Comment: df1.writeStream.queryName(f"display1").format(
        "delta"
    ).foreachBatch(
        lambda dataframe, _: fun1(spark, path,df1)
    ).trigger(
        processingTime="30 seconds"
    ).outputMode(
        "update"
    ).start()
    
 
updated_df = func(spark, df_with_signals)

query=updated_df.writeStream.queryName("display2").format(
        "delta"
    ).foreachBatch(
        lambda dataframe, _: fun2(spark, dataframe)
    ).trigger(
        processingTime="2 seconds"
    ).outputMode(
        "update"
    )